# Which compiler settings are changed when I change target device?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS project that builds fine for simulators, but which has compiler errors when built for a Generic Device or when I try to run on a real device through Xcode. NOTE: actual compiler errors, not linker or deployment errors. The errors are to do with mismatched types in typedefs - as if it's including headers from a different SDK, or has different preprocessor defines.

My question is - what compiler settings are changed when I change target device in the Xcode UI and where can I view the differences? I cannot see any differences when I look at the project settings and change the target device - specifically the deployment target version and SDK version appear unchanged.

The project used to build fine with any of these target devices under Xcode 7, but does not under Xcode 8. I suspect this is down to the version of the SDK that comes with Xcode. But for it to work with some target devices and not others it has to be changing compiler settings. This should be really simple to fix, if only I could see what changes it's making!

Here's the line (in my code) which fails to compile:

```
typedef     void*           IOSurfaceRef;
```

And here's the error message:

```
error: typedef redefinition with different types ('void *' vs 'struct __IOSurface *')
```

*Please note I don't want help fixing the error or advice on what it's trying to do - **I know it's not good**.* I'd just like to know which compiler settings are changed by switching target device.

Comment: Update your question with actual relevant code related to the error and post the complete, exact, actual errors.

Comment: Thanks, that's a reasonable request. However, I don't want help fixing the errors - I'm asking what compiler settings are changed by changing the target device and fear posting the code will derail into questions about why the code does $HIGHLY_QUESTIONABLE_THING...

Comment: Is that your typedef or is it in some Apple/3rd party code?

Comment: It's in my code, and it's deliberately trying (and now failing, for some but not all target devices) to pretend to be an alias for Apple's IOSurfaceRef. I will not attempt to defend it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because `CGBase.h` contains this code:

```
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

typedef struct  CF_BRIDGED_TYPE(id) __IOSurface *IOSurfaceRef __attribute__((swift_name("IOSurfaceRef")));

#endif
```

When you are building for a device the `#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` preprocessor directive is true, so your code has two `typedef`s for `IOSurfaceRef` with conflicting types.

Comment: Thanks. It appears CGBase.h from the iOS SDK that came with Xcode 7 does not have a declaration for IOSurfaceRef, hence it working before.

Comment: So the answer to my question as phrased is "When changing target device, preprocessor directives (e.g. TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) are changed"